# Live Agent Pre-Chat API: Disable creating new case

Tags: visualforce, liveagent

I am trying to create a case using [liveagent prechat API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_pre_chat_forms_code_sample.htm) as explained in this link http://peterknolle.com/live-agent-pre-chat-api/. The case is created successfully but there is also a new case open along side as shown in the screenshot. How can I stop this new case from opening as I have already created a new case?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because when you have added Liveagent console to an app you might have specified to open New Case form.

[image]